# Fetching my key from an .env file and it is missing characters

Tags: node.js

I define PAYTM_KEY=Vkp%y6xcAImxxx1P# in .env file.

but i get in colsole:- PAYTM_KEY: 'Vkp%y6xcAImxxx1P'

why # is missing ?

Comment: Have you try addin quotes in your env file: PAYTM_KEY="Vkp%y6xcAImktc1P#"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The # start a comment so you need to quote your ENV var, like this:

```
PAYTM_KEY="Vkp%y6xcAImktc1P#"
```

Without quote, the # char is interpreted as the beginning of a comment.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to vote and checkmark the answer.